# Regex from jQuery source

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I understand most of this regex but not | at the end of each parenthesis. I know it can be used like this (a(b|c)). That will match both ab and ac. If it was in [] it would match the actual symbol "|". Help me understand this.

```
// Used for matching numbers
core_pnum = /[+-]?(?:\d*\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)/.source
```

Comment: Could it mean "this or nothing"? My Regex is rusty...

Comment: You are looking for this?
http://goo.gl/I40Uhl

Comment: @Zac The first parentheses will then say zero or more digits followed by a dot or nothing. Maybe you are right. Why not use the "?" instead then?

Comment: @user874774 it certainly sounds silly. I don't really know the context so maybe it was just easier to write the regex that way as opposed to the alternative (as written by M42 below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?:\d*\.|)` means

A non-capture group that contains 0 or more digits followed by a dot or nothing at all.

It could be rewritten like:

```
(?:\d*\.)?
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[+-]?(?:\d*\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/opsi-4SbgPPbzPlV)

You basically see, that it can mean "optional". Try to remove the | from the RegEx and the graphical representation shows this pretty neat.

Replacing it with `?` would show the same result (except that the the line in the drawing is on top instead of the bottom)

```
[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/QkANg5ry-KacNcwM)

Comment: So that applies to the whole parentheses?

Comment: Everything in the brackets (see M42's answer with the ? after the brackets)

Comment: Yes, exactly. `(?:\d*\.)` would make it required. Making it optional, allows to write e.g -4 while removing | would not allow this.

Comment: (?:\d*\.|) is same as (?:\d*\.)?. You live example suggest not.

Comment: Ok then I understand!. Thanks. I would like to give the correct answer to both.